# Let $(X_{1},\ldots,X_{N})\overset{d}{=}(Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{N})$. Show that $P(X_{1}<\cdots <X_{N})=P(Y_{1}<\cdots <Y_{N})$

Tags: self-study, distributions, probability-inequalities

Let $(X_{1},\ldots,X_{N})\overset{d}{=}(Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{N})$. Show that $P(X_{1}<\cdots <X_{N})=P(Y_{1}<\cdots <Y_{N})$.

**Remark:** I know that the equality in distribution is preserved under measurable functions, but I do not know how to use it.  Actually, I do not know if this fact works in this situation.

Comment: If both vectors have the same distribution, any event $A$ has the same probability for both vectors, $$\mathbb{E}^\mathbf{X}[\mathbb{I}_A(\mathbf{X})]=\mathbb{E}^\mathbf{Y}[\mathbb{I}_A(\mathbf{Y})]$$

Comment: Isn't this result a direct consequence of the meaning of having the same distribution?  If not, then please tell us what your definition of  "$\overset{d}{=}$" is.